# apache 404 with php pages for wiki installation

Tags: apache2

So i followed some pretty clear instructions on getting a wiki setup on ubuntu 16, but i'm failing.

http://idroot.net/linux/install-dokuwiki-ubuntu-16-04/

I can gedt to apache default page with server IP address but when i enter /install.php or /index.php or /doku.php   i get 404 URL not found.  permissions seem correct any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Thought there be another way but i had to change the root directory of Apache.  I'm still learning.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include your default 000-default.conf file contents? It will be located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`